# How to use two skeleton templates in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

There are two wrapper components `WrapperComponent1` and `WrapperComponent2`. Inside them is `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

They are differ only HTML:

**WrapperComponent1**

```
<div class="wrap1">
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**WrapperComponent2**

```
<div class="wrap2">
     <div class="menu"></div>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 </div>
```

I want to show `RegisterComponent` inside `WrapperComponent1` and `LoginComponent` inside `WrapperComponent2`.

How to build route?

I tried:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "register", component: RegistrationComponent },
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [ChildRoutes](https://angular.io/guide/router#child-routing-component) function of the Angular router.

You define 2 main  empty path that load your 2 different wrap components and then define  the 2 real routes as child routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: WrapperComponent1,
        children: [
            path: 'register', component: RegistrationComponent }
        ]
    },
  { path: '', component: WrapperComponent2,
        children: [
            path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
        ]
    }
];
```

**UPDATE:**

Be sure to have at least one `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in all *parent* components in your route tree aswell in your main app.component.

Comment: Also, please edit answer and say that dobt forget use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>
` inside boot App.component